# Different credit card choices for each payment processor

Tags: civicontribute, payment-processor

I have one payment processor set up that only accepts VISA and MasterCard. I have a different payment processor set up that only accepts American Express. Both use the Authorize.net style payment processor APIs.

I have added both payment processors to my contribution page. But all credit card choices (VISA, MasterCard and American Express) are offered to the visitor no matter which payment processor is selected.

How should I configure this?

(FYI: I already checked the settings at http://mygroup.org/civicrm/admin/options/accept_creditcard?reset=1  but the settings there seem to be global, not per payment processor.)

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a way to do that out of the box - I think the only way to get that functionality would be a custom extension